# Compile app with OpenCV 2.4 in Windows 7 command line

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, windows-7-x64

I download OpenCV 2.4 extracted into `C:\OpenCV2.4`. Added one system variables `OPENCV_DIR=C:\OpenCV2.4\build` and added to PATH the following `%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\bin`

My code looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

int main(){
   IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("imagen.jpg");
   if(!img){
      std::cout << "File not found\n" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Now from the command-line tool I tried something like:

`cl testCV.cpp /IC:\OpenCV2.4\build\include`

and get the following error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\intrin.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or directory`

How can I compile this program with cl.exe? I cannot achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install [SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/31/10148110.aspx) , this should hook yo up :)

Please also take a look at this nice [blog](http://wishmesh.com/2011/04/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ammintrin-h-no-such-file-or-directory/)

Comment: Yep, If I were you I'd give it a try

Comment: When using the option `/I` to indicate the include path, is there a way to use some system variable? something like `/I$(OPENCV_PATH)\include` ??

Comment: Try this  /I%OPENCV_PATH%\include